# Error Eslint: terminated with error timeout in Brackets

Tags: javascript, timeout, eslint, brackets

[image]

There is no code in the editor, however this problem exists !!

Answer (score 1):

if the first extenstion didn't work ,the second (brackets-eslint) must work

Answer (score 1):

Install extension eslint sometimes this extension also doesn't work so other option is to add brackets-eslint extension this will surly work and remove timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

just update eslint and it will work ^_^

[image]